# Show normal buttons instead of radio buttons

Tags: c#, botframework, facebook-messenger-bot

I used a Hero Card to show some buttons but they have limitations as it concerns the text length. Now I am trying to use adaptive cards but I cannot manage to show normal buttons instead of radio buttons.

```
List<string> options= new List<string>();
```

> fill the list and continue to create the card

```
AdaptiveCard ac = new AdaptiveCard()
{
    Body = new List<CardElement>()
    {
        new TextBlock()
        {
            Color = TextColor.Attention,
            Weight = TextWeight.Bolder,
            Size = TextSize.Medium,
            Text = "My title",
        },
        new ChoiceSet()
        {
            Id = "title",
            Style = ChoiceInputStyle.Expanded,
            IsRequired = false,
            IsMultiSelect = false,
            Value = "1",
            Choices = options.Select(item => new Choice { Title = item, Value = item }).ToList(),
        },
    },
};
```

As you can see I have a list of text values which I fill before the adaptive card. Then I created a TextBlock to show a title and after that the ChoiceSet to display the buttons. What am I doing wrong and the buttons keep appearing as radio buttons.

Comment: You've tagged this with facebook-messenger-bot but Facebook Messenger does not support Adaptive Cards. Are you actually seeing interactive radio buttons in Messenger or are you only seeing them when you test in Emulator and Web Chat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Kyle Delaney's comment Adaptive Cards are not supported on messenger yet. Although they offer more functionalities than other rich cards unfortunately they can't be used. I found a solution by sticking to Hero Cards and following a different flow whenever the text length of a button is bigger than the permitted one.

Comment: Since I did not find a different solution then yes